# Scipy with boost::python functions

Tags: c++, python, boost, scipy

everybody.
I try to find a minimum of a function that I've exported in a *.pyd file using boost::python.

```
def SaturationDensity(C):
    return optimize.minimize(lambda z:SNM_BED(z, C), 1.0)

def SNM_BED(n, C):
    return eos.t_E(0.5*n, 0.5*n, C)/(Dim*n) - m_n
```

where eos is the name of the module. In scipy.optimize.minimize routine it fails in the line

```
#optimize.py
def wrap_function(function, args):
    ncalls = [0]
    def function_wrapper(x):
        ncalls[0] += 1
        return function(x, *args) # <---Here
    return ncalls, function_wrapper
```

with `Boost.Python.ArgumentError:Python argument types in eos.t_E(numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, KVOR) did not match C++ signature: t_E(double, double, class set_const *)`

so scipy tries to pass a ndarray directly to my C++ function.
(KVOR is an inherited from set_const class, and it is not a problem).

I tried to replace `return function(x, *args)` with `return map(lambda z: function(z, *args), x)`, but it seems that not only lists (ndarrays) are passed here as `x`, but also the scalars, so map reports an error.

Also I tried to check whether x is iterable or not, using the following code:

```
try:
    it = iter(x)
except TypeError:
    return function(x, *args)

return map(lambda z: function(z, *args),x)
```

but it fails in another place in `optimize.py`:

`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 589, in approx_fprime
    grad = numpy.zeros((len(xk),), float)
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()`

I've got some problems like this in I don't remember which function of `scipy`, but I could resolve it using `map`. Is it a common problem of the all scipy functions? And what to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `n = float(n)` on top of your SNM_BED routine.

Typically 1-element ndarrays are cast automatically to floats when needed, but boost::python seems to be too picky to do this.